# Access linked server table collation

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I've got Access application, that has some Linked Tables linked to our SQL Server through Linked Table Manager:

[image]

Now issue is that in database, all of those tables have collation, which is different than default database collation and I'd like to change that in order to have things consistent.

There's not much information about that on internet, or I couldn't find it (excuse me).

So question is whether things would break in Access if I changed collation to databse default in SQL Server? I don't dare to try right now because there's no proper development environment and it's semi-production one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the properties of ODBC connection you used when you created the linked tables.

ODBC use Data driver which is responsible to tanslating data from/to server based on the local of client /collation of table.

For [Sql server driver ] and [Sql server Native client xx] where xx may be 11 /12 based on the installed sql client, there is a property named:

```
 perform translation for character data
```

The default is checked. Review it and check it (if not checked).

In that case the driver translate character data (whatever its collation) to the local of the client.

I did POC (Proof Of Concept) and created a table in database in sql server 2012 and assigned different Collation, then created linked table in access 2007.

The data is retrieved successfully in the same local of the access database.

Other check: Test reading your table in VBA using ADO /DAO and be sure that data is retrieved successfully.

Comment: This seems useful. Thanks a lot :)